# How is django's default cache invalidated by an app

Tags: python, django, caching

I've had to disable django's cache middleware;

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    #'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    ...
    #'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
)
```

This is because it is caching views by default, causing incorrect information to be rendered because our methods don't invalidate the cache.

I'm familiar with writing custom cache methods for my models and the necessary signals to delete cache keys, but if django is creating cache keys itself, how do I delete the correct keys when I change an object for example?